# MPMoviePlayerController wont play

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

It feels like this should be somewhere here on SO. However I can't find it...

I'm trying to use an MPMoviePlayerController, but the problem is that exactly nothing happens. I don't even get an error...

Here's some code:

```
NSURL *movieUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[attachmentDictionary objectForKey:@"Uri"]];
    NSLog(@"URI %@", movieUrl);
    MPMoviePlayerController *mediaController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieUrl];


    [mediaController prepareToPlay];
    [mediaController.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:mediaController.view];

    [mediaController play];
```

I have included the MediaPlayer Framework, and MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h.

Do you have any idea of what might be wrong?

EDIT:

Found out that I get this error code:

```
2012-09-28 09:45:57.346 Famorable[178:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2012-09-28 09:45:57.348 Famorable[178:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2012-09-28 09:45:57.435 Famorable[178:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it!

It's the ARC spooking again by releasing the MPMoviePlayerController before it played... By declaring the property in the header file you're good to go!